# REG_SZ value saved as Japanese text

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a few values to the Windows registry through `RegSetValueEx`, however, the values save in "Japanese form".
For example:

"整瑳湩ㅧ㌲" should be "testing123"

When looking at the text in a hex editor, the text appears to be the correct value, but with "FF FE" prepended, which seems to be a byte order mark.

The code to save the value is as follows:

```
RegSetValueEx(
    RegistryUtils::registryKey,
    L"test",
    0,
    REG_SZ,
    (unsigned char*)config.getTestValue().c_str(),
    strlen(config.getTestValue().c_str()) + 1
);
```

where `config.getTestValue()` returns a `std::string` type.

How can I prevent "FF FE" being prepended to the desired string?

Comment: This function is actually a macro --- it might be expanding to the Unicode version of the function, as many methods do.  Call explicitly `RegSetValueExA` (for ANSI), and see if that works.  You still need the wide-string as the second parameter.

Comment: You're passing a wide string `L"test"` as one argument, yet using the narrow string `strlen` for the last argument. Which is it? Mixing and matching narrow and wide strings does not help.

Comment: @MaxBozzi The prototype of `RegSetValueEx` says `LPCTSTR lpValueName` - that means that when using the `RegSetValueExA`, the second argument should be a narrow string too.

Answer (score 1):

The string data for `RegSetValueExW` needs to be wide text, and the size argument needs to be number of bytes, including the terminating zero.

This works nicely:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <string.h>     // strlen

namespace RegistryUtils
{
    auto const registryKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    wchar_t const* const s = L"blah";

    RegSetValueEx(
        RegistryUtils::registryKey,
        L"test",
        0,
        REG_SZ,
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE const*>( s ),
        sizeof(wchar_t)*(wcslen(s) + 1)
    );
}
```

It's a good idea to read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a problematic function.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Unicode version of `RegSetValueEx()`, which expects string data in UTF-16 format, but you are passing Ansi data instead.  Put your data into a `std::wstring` instead of a `std::string`, and also keep in mind that `RegSetValueEx()` operates on bytes, not not characters:

```
std::wstring value = config.getTestValueW(); // <-- for you to implement
RegSetValueEx(
    RegistryUtils::registryKey,
    L"test",
    0,
    REG_SZ,
    (BYTE*) value.c_str(),
    (value.length() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)
);
```

Comment: The `const_cast` is a bit unnecessary. (The C style cast `(BYTE*)` here performs both a `const_cast` and a `reinterpret_cast`)